# Javascript JSZip having error after adding image

Tags: javascript, node.js, jszip

I would like to download some a tampermonkey script that help me download images from a website and then packed as a zip file for me to download. I used [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) for packing the images.

I have no problem following the sample code but when an image is added, then I would get the following error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid base64 input, it looks like a data url.
```

I placed my code in [Runkit](https://runkit.com/winstonma/jszipimagefail), if line 19 is commented (didn't add the downloaded image into the zip file) everything will run smoothly. I am not sure how could I could add the image into the zip file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of the problem is the downloaded image didn't follow the base64 requirement. There is nothing wrong with the `JSZip` part.

Here are different ways to download the image properly:

> **Node**
>
> I managed to replace the image downloading library from [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)
> to [node-base64-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-base64-image) and everything is working now. I guess you
> can still use request but need to tune the parameters in order to get
> that work. Here is the working [Runkit](https://runkit.com/winstonma/jszip-image-success). So in conclusion the
> problem is on download side.

> **Browser**
>
> As I want to download the image from the using a browser script
> ([tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/)) so the node solution doesn't fit me. After
> searching a bit I find a working solution:
>
> ```
>         GM_xmlhttpRequest({
>             method: "GET",
>             url: url,
>             headers: { referer: url, origin: url },
>             responseType: 'blob',
>             onload: response => {
>                 // Here the response.response would be the image that works for JSZip
>             }
>         });
> ```